# How To Distinct 'or' condition in a Query

Tags: sql, ssms

```
WITH 
    irelevant as (
    SELECT [Entity_Number] from  [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Entity_Events]
    where Event_Code in ('1552', '1567')) -- כל הבקשות שקיבלו קוד 1552,1567 לסינון בהמשך השאילתה

SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [IB_Bakasha].[Tik_Binian] ASC) AS OID
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Tik_Binian]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Number]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Description]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Ikari_Area]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Y_Diur]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Floors_Requested_Number]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Basement_Floors]
      ,[IB_Entity_Events].[Entity_Number]
      ,[IB_Entity_Events].[Event_Code]
      ,[IB_Entity_Events].[Event_Date]

      FROM [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Bakasha]
          join [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Entity_Events] on [Bakasha_Number]= [IB_Entity_Events.[Entity_Number]
      where 
      [IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Number] not in (select * from irelevant)
      and ([IB_Entity_Events].[Event_Code] = '1100' or [IB_Entity_Events].[Event_Code] = '1101')
      and  [Table_Number] = '2'
      and [Maslul_Code] = '1'
```

The query retrives record from a table the stores requests of users.
Each request identified by the [Bakasha_Number] field.
One request can apear in several records with different [Event_Code] which means the request has gone through several stages in the process.
I want the records that has [Event_Code] of either 1100 or 1101.

 But, and here i need help:
when one request eppears twice once with [Event_Code] of 1100 and once of 1101 i want only the record with [Event_Code] of 1100 to be selected.

In other words:
if one request id ([Bakasha_Number]) has one event code - select it 
if one request id ([Bakasha_Number]) has both event codes - select only 1100

Any suggestion how can i do it?

I tried to create subselcetion but it got too comlicated and unreadable

Comment: What is your DBMS? Tag the question accordingly please. And sql table consists of rows, not records. Some DBMSes support a record type data. Although it's quite clear what you mean here use a correct term to avoid a possible confusion.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @serg i use Microsoft SQL Server i  hope 'ssms' is the correct tag

Comment: @Tal `ssms` is not the correct tag.  `sql-server` is the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second CTE based on IB_Entity_Events, to prioritize the Event_Codes in the way you want them prioritized; then join to that. Like so:

```
WITH 
    irelevant as (
    SELECT [Entity_Number] from  [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Entity_Events]
    where Event_Code in ('1552', '1567')), -- כל הבקשות שקיבלו קוד 1552,1567 לסינון בהמשך השאילתה

    ee as
    (
        select
            Entity_Number,
            Event_Code,
            Event_Date,
            row_number() over
            (
                partition by
                    Entity_Number
                order by
                    Event_Code asc
            ) as Priority_Number
        from
            [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Entity_Events]
        where
            [Event_Code] in ('1100', '1101')
    )

SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [IB_Bakasha].[Tik_Binian] ASC) AS OID
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Tik_Binian]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Number]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Description]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Ikari_Area]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Y_Diur]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Floors_Requested_Number]
      ,[IB_Bakasha].[Basement_Floors]
      ,ee.Entity_Number
      ,ee.Event_Code
      ,ee.Event_Date

      FROM [HFA_M].[dbo].[IB_Bakasha]
          join ee on [Bakasha_Number]= ee.Entity_Number and ee.Priority_Number = 1
      where 
      [IB_Bakasha].[Bakasha_Number] not in (select * from irelevant)
      and  [Table_Number] = '2'
      and [Maslul_Code] = '1'
```